# Last filled cell in excel sheet by Python win32

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to find the last cell in an excel worksheet by Python win32 module, but somehow it doesn't seem to recognize End(xlDown).
Program line-

```
LastRow = WBName.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,2).End(xlDown).Row
```

The error-

> NameError: name 'xlDown' is not defined

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `xlDown` corresponds to `-4121`, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection).

Answer (score 0):

win32c = win32.constants

```
  XlApp.Visible = 1
  wb = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(Input) 
  ws = wb.ActiveSheet
  excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    lr = XlApp.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(win32c.xlShiftUp).Row
  print(lr)
```

or

```
def LastRow(WS,COL):
      return WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, COL).End(win32c.xlShiftUp).Row

print(LastRow(ws,"a"))
```